# Permission for owner that user account

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I building 2 permission for the user account owner and the apartment owner. Although they have the same code, the user account owner doesn't work.

permissions.py

```py
class IsOwnerUserOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.username == request.user # Not Work


class IsOwnerApartmentOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.seller == request.user  # Work OK
```

views.py

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerUserOrReadOnly]

class ApartmentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Apartment.objects.filter(issold=False).order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ApartmentSerializer
    # Set permission for only user owner apartment can edit it.
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerApartmentOrReadOnly]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the return expression of the first permission class is not correct. It should be `obj`, not `obj.username` because `request.user` is the instance of the User model.

```
class IsOwnerUserOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj == request.user # Not Work
```